# Sending videos with telebot from Google Drive

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

I want to send a video to the user with telebot in Telegram through a google drive link
In normal mode, it sends the movie by giving a link
like this:

```
g_link = "https://drive.google.com/uc?/export=download&id=xxx"
bot.send_video(chat_id_,g_link)
```

But when the file in Google Drive is more than 100 megabytes, my code no longer works
What should I add?